# Prove that $\theta = 90^{\circ}$

Tags: geometry

Knowing that BQRP is a square, prove that $\theta = 90^{\circ}$.

I can't relate the angle $\theta$ to the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. All relationships generate equality.[image: Figura 1]

for example: $180^{\circ} - \theta - \alpha - \beta - 90^{\circ} + \alpha + \beta + \theta = 90^{\circ} \implies 90^{\circ} = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: I don't know why your teacher wrote :$\measuredangle QRC=\alpha+\beta$ because it was on you to see the obvious: $$\Delta PAR\sim\Delta QRC\sim\Delta BAC$$ Of course $$\measuredangle PAR=\measuredangle QRC$$ This task has already been solved in the picture so I'm voting to close. Whoever gave you this, he/ she ruined the joy and excitement. 

Comment: I wasn't a teacher. I put it for easier viewing. But I need to demonstrate algebraically that theta is 90 degrees

Comment: I think that if we can demonstrate that <HBC is congruent to <CRQ the problem will be solved: -90^o + theta + alpha + beta = alpha + beta then theta= 90^o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{AP}{PB} \cdot \frac{BQ}{QC} \cdot \frac {CH}{HA}=1 
\\ PB=PR,BQ=QR\implies \frac{AP}{PR} \cdot \frac{QR}{QC} \cdot \frac {CH}{HA}=1\\
\Delta_{ABC} \sim\Delta_{APR}\sim \Delta_{RQC} \implies \frac{AB}{BC} \cdot \frac{AB}{BC} \cdot \frac {CH}{HA}=1\\
\implies \frac{AH}{CH} = \frac{AB^2}{BC^2}\\
 \implies \frac{AH}{CH} + 1 = \frac{AB^2}{BC^2} +1\\
\implies \frac{AH+CH}{CH} = \frac{AB^2+BC^2}{BC^2} \\
\implies \frac{AC}{CH} = \frac{AC^2(*Pythagorean ~Theorem)}{BC^2}\\
\implies \frac{AC}{CH} = \frac{AC^2}{BC^2}\\
\implies \frac{{{\color{red}{AC}}}}{CH} = \frac{AC^\color{red}{2}}{BC.BC}\\
\implies \frac{AC}{BC} = \frac{BC}{CH}\\
 \implies \triangle ABC \sim \triangle BHC\\
\implies\boxed{ B\hat{H}C =\theta = 90^o}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is my read of the question:

> In $\triangle ABC$ with $ \angle ABC = 90^\circ$, construct square $BPRQ$ with $R$ on $AC$. Let $AQ$ and $CP$ intersect at $T$. Show that $BT$ is perpendicular to $AC$.

---

The hard part is relating $H$ to anything else, which clearly needs to be done through $T$.

Apply Cevas on point $T$ in triangle $ABC$.

$$\frac{ BP}{PA} \times \frac{AH}{HC} \times \frac{ CQ}{QB} = 1 $$

Can you take it from here?

> Since $ \frac {AH}{HC} = \frac{AP}{CQ} = \tan^2 \angle BCA$, hence $H$ is indeed the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$.

Comment: Hi Calvin.
sorry for my difficulty but could explain better AH/HC = AP/CQ = tan^2<BCA --> H is perpendicular from B to AC

Comment: Let point $D$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$. Can you show that $ \frac{ AD}{DC} = \tan^2 \angle BCA$? If yes, then it follows that $D = H$.

Comment: I don't understand tg ^ 2 <BCA = AD / DC.
tg < BCA wouldn't  be AB / BC?

Comment: If you can explain I appreciate!

Comment: It's just angle chasing which you've essentially done. Since $ \angle BCA = \angle ABH$, $ \tan \angle BCA = DB / DC$ and $ \tan \angle ABH = AD / DB$, hence $ AD / DC = \tan^2 \angle BCA$.